# SAPUI5 Can't access a array and give it to a JSONModel

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have problems to access an array, where i put some data from a omodel read. The array is called aData und contains row data for a table. This works fine, all data is in there.

This all code is done after a value help dialog is opened and in his/this table i want to put the data

```
        var oTestModel = this.getModel();
        oTestModel.read("/shrhelpSet", {
            filters: [oFilterObject, oFilterField, oFilterLang],
            success: function(oRetrieveResults){
                //console.log(oRetrieveResults);

                var oDatas2 = oRetrieveResults;
                var test1 = oDatas2.results;

                var aData = [];
                var index = oDatas2.results.length;
                var i;
                for (i=0; i<index; i++) {       

                    aData.push("{Key: '" + oDatas2.results[i].key + "', Value: '" + oDatas2.results[i].value + "'}");
                }

                // aData Array  
                console.log("aData: " + aData);

            },

            error: function(oError){
                console.log(oError);
            }
        });
```

This code is after the omodel read. Here i have an array with column data for my table. 
The oModel2 contains the columndata, which i definded in aColumnData
and the rows from above are in aData. And here is the problem. It returns (the array) no data or is showing only object. Do you have tipps for better handling this or a solution for this problem?

```
        var aColumnData = [{
            columnId: "Key"
        }, {
            columnId: "Value"
        }];

        var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        oModel2.setData({
            columns: aColumnData,
            rows: aData // THIS IS THE RESULT OF MY MODEL, the results are in aData but i cant access it here
        });

        oTable.setModel(oModel2);

        oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
            var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
            return new sap.ui.table.Column({
                id : sColumnId,
                label: sColumnId,
                template: sColumnId
            });
        });
        oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

Comment: Does the second piece of code follow the first one directly? If so, the success method is probably not yet started when you are trying to use the array to fill your model. Is it not an option to bind your table to oTestModel?

Comment: Yes its following directly. Are you sure. Its finished and then it goes to the second piece. I am sure that its successfull to. The problem to bind the table to oTestModel was that i cannot bind it because its a sap.ui.table. I tried it, but the solution what works for me was this what i have. I dont know, maybe i did something wrong too

Comment: Is the aData array empty or is aData not defined? Because it looks like you declare it inside the success handler and try to access it outside. Could you try to declare the variable "aData" before "oTestModel.read(...)". If this doesn't help, then Samleijenhorst might be right because the "read" is asynchronous. This means, the success handler will run when data is received. This might be after your second snipped is run already.

Comment: Now i definded it outside. The aData is empty after the run. Can you explain me please why the code after the read is called first than the read itself. I dont understand this. I am new to sapui5 / javascript

Comment: What possibilities i have to get the data out of a asynchronous call, because i mean, with the recieved data everybody has to work on his application

Comment: Would something like this work: var aData = oModelread...(function (, ) {
    
    return aResult;

Comment: The success handler will run as soon as data is received from the network. This is asynchronous which means that the code execution will not stop and wait for the data from the backend, it will keep runnung until the data is received. At this point, the success handler will run. You cannot know when exactly the sucess handler will run because it depends on the speed of the backend response. I will add an answer for you to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the code that needs access to the received data into the success handler like this. Also, I think the other answer is right that you need to create objects instead of strings.

```
this.getModel().read("/shrhelpSet", {
filters: [oFilterObject, oFilterField, oFilterLang],
success: function (oRetrieveResults) {
    var aData = oRetrieveResults.results.map(function (oResult) {
        return {
            Key: oResult.key,
            Value: oResult.value
        };
    });

    var aColumnData = [{
        columnId: "Key"
    }, {
        columnId: "Value"
    }];

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        columns: aColumnData,
        rows: aData
    });

    oTable.setModel(oModel);

    oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function (index, context) {
        var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
        return new sap.ui.table.Column({
            id: sColumnId,
            label: sColumnId,
            template: sColumnId
        });
    });

    oTable.bindRows("/rows");
}.bind(this),

error: function (oError) {
    console.log(oError);
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution. I have to get more into the procedure of asynchronous , models, ui5 etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem could be that you are pushing strings and not objects in your array:

```
aData.push("{Key: '" + oDatas2.results[i].key + "', Value: '" + oDatas2.results[i].value + "'}");
```

Your object should be something like this:

```
{
   Key: oDatas2.results[i].key,
   Value: oDatas2.results[i].value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no problem with your view.

```js
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
  rows: '{/rows}',
  title: new sap.m.Title({
    text: "Test"
  })
});

oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(index, context) {
  var sColumnId = context.getObject().columnId;
  return new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: sColumnId,
    template: sColumnId
  });
});

var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  columns: [{
    columnId: "Key"
  }, {
    columnId: "Value"
  }],
  rows: [
    { Key: "K1", Value: "V1" },
    { Key: "K2", Value: "V2" },
  ] 
});

oTable.setModel(model);
oTable.placeAt('content');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
    <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.m" 
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"></script> 
  </head>
  <body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact">
  </body>
</html>
```

So it appears that your model is incorrect. Maybe you are trying to change the results in the model like this.

```
success: function(oRetrieveResults){
    var aData = oRetrieveResults.results.map(function(data) {
        return {
            Key: '"' + data.key + '"',
            Value: '"' + data.value + '"'
        };
    });
    this.setProperty("/results", oData);
},
```

Comment: No i am not changing it, i am only copying out the key and value to save it in an array